# Create a email validation in react with apisauce and textinput

Tags: react-native, api

I'm trying to create an email validation for my app with react-native, I created a  code to test it, but I want to create a text input for it, how can I do that? here's my code

```
export default class Signin extends Component 
  state ={
    errorMessage: null
  }
  signin = async() => {
    try{
      const response = await api.post('/auth/authenticate',{
        email:'teste@teste.com',
        password: '123'
      })
  
      const {user, token} = response.data
      console.log(response.data)
  
      await AsyncStorage.multiSet([
        ['@backend:token', token],
        ['@backend:user', JSON.stringify(user)]
      ])

      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.Container}>
           { this.state.errorMessage && <Text>{ this.state.errorMessage }</Text> }
        
        <Button onPress={this.signin} title="Entrar"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
    
}
```

how you could see it already have a test email in there, but how can I create a input ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use validator.js isEmail method, it is compatible with react-native and so easy. https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: I was thinking in use textinput

Comment: So you would like to test, there is an email form in the input value?

Comment: no, I pre-loaded an email therer, I want to create this